# How to get timesyncd details?

Tags: systemd, ntp, ntpd

**How can I get detailed information about the NTP status of my system, when using `systemd-timesyncd` as the time client?**

The closest one I found is

```
# timedatectl status
                      Local time: Wed 2019-06-05 09:03:09 CEST
                  Universal time: Wed 2019-06-05 07:03:09 UTC
                        RTC time: Wed 2019-06-05 07:03:09
                       Time zone: Europe/Paris (CEST, +0200)
       System clock synchronized: no
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

but this only gives me very general information. Specifically, there is no information about which peers I am connected to, the delay/drift etc.

How can I get the information I would be normally getting via `ntpq` if using `ntpd` (or `chrony`)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using Ubuntu or another distro in Debian. `timesyncd` is a small client-only NTP implementation bundled with `systemd` releases. Unfortunately, `systemd-timesyncd` does no clock discipline, so it could definitely cause problems for distributed systems that want greater time precision.

However, based on your purpose, you also can use timesyncd. I focus two lines of timedatectl status.

`system clock synchronized: no` means that the time has **not** been successfully synced.
`systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes` means that timesyncd is enabled

so you need to recheck the timesyncd configuration, then restart systemd service.

To see verbose timesyncd information, use `timedatectl timesync-status` command. With this, you see "Offset", "Delay", "Jitter" and Frequency, Root distance. They are very useful for troubleshooting.

Can you switch to ntpd? This is the traditional tool. Then you can use `ntpd` (standard NTP query program) `ntpstat` (network time synchronisation status)

You can refer more [here](https://lintut.com/how-to-verify-ntp-setup-is-working-properly-in-linux-or-unix-server/).

Comment: `timedatectl timesync-status` does not exist on my system (systemd 237 on Ubuntu 18.04) - this is actually the kind of command I was looking for. I used `ntpd` and `chrony` for years but wanted to go full systemd (and since it provides time keeping utilities why not)

Comment: Unfortunately, same to you, I read many times man page of timedatectl, and realize that timedatectl uses to query and set/ change the system clock. It doesn't sync the date time with NTP server. So you still need to install chrony or ntpd for time synchronisation.

Comment: It does synchronize with the NTP servers, you can see the logs when it starts up (the servers which were taken into account for the synchronization are listed). It is just that afterwards I did not find a way to check the status.

Comment: Output of `timedatectl timesync-status` on a raspberry-pi 3b+ (Debian 11, network configuration via `dhcp`, local DSL-router includes a NTP-Server): ```root@rpi:~# timedatectl timesync-status
       Server: 192.168.178.1 (192.168.178.1)
Poll interval: 34min 8s (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)
         Leap: normal
      Version: 4
      Stratum: 3
    Reference: 6F5607D
    Precision: 1us (-20)
Root distance: 25.069ms (max: 5s)
       Offset: -464us
        Delay: 1.116ms
       Jitter: 1.453ms
 Packet count: 3284
    Frequency: -8.911ppm
```